# how to use where() with array in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

I have a column like this :

[image]

and i've gotten this array

```
"specification" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "27"
    1 => "26"
    2 => "24"
  ]
```

how can I compare these two with eloquent like this :

```
SpecificationItemGroup::where('specification_items', [$request->specification])->get()
```

Comment: print your query and compare... may be `[]` is no need in where condition...

Comment: @hassan try this SpecificationItemGroup::where('specification_items', $request->specification)->get()

Comment: @wadleo does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're storing it as `json encoded` string, you should try encoding the array and compare it

```
SpecificationItemGroup::where('specification_items', json_encode($request->specification))->get()
```